# VSCode Class method hint for PHP

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I had written classes for a project in different class files.

In the main file I had included these classes, and created instances from them.
There is many method in there, and i cannot remember all names.

Is there a solution is VSCode for class method hinting like intellisense, when i typing the object in?

Example:

```
<?php
include "Some.class.php";
$var = new Some();
$var-> //[CTRL + Space] gives me PHP built in methods, not the class methods.
?>
```

Comment: In a word, [docblocks](http://www.phpdoc.org/)

Comment: Use sublime or phpstorm editor

Comment: What do you mean docblocks? I not want to write comment blocks for each method. Anyway this is not working for intellysense too, because it is an another file.

Comment: It's a couple of years later. is this still not implemented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an old question, but it is possible.

I am using the PHP Intelephense extension by Ben Mewburn:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client

Install it and you can do something like the following:

```php
<?php

include "Some.class.php";

/**
 * This hints what type the variable is
 * @var \Some $var 
 */
$var = new Some();
$var->
```

And now you vscode will give you a list of available methods on the object `$var`

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know there is no such thing yet.

However they are working on plugin support:

> We plan to offer plugin support for Visual Studio Code. Thank you for your interests and look for more details in our blog in the coming weeks.
>
> For the preview we are looking for exactly this type of feedback. Keep it coming.
>
> Sean McBreen – VS Code Team Member

[link](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/7752408-plugin-system)

and adding **php** intellisense is being discussed:

> Hi,
>
> Our extensibility story will definitely support plug-ins for languages like PHP. This will enable authors to develop IntelliSense and Debugging support in additional languages.
>
> That said, we know a lot of PHP users are interested in Code and we are investigating what we can do to make the experience better for PHP as well.
>
> We don’t have a timeline to share currently or any firm roadmap statement but it’s something we are discussing.
>
> Sean McBreen
> Visual Studio Code – Team Member

[link](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/7752606-php-intellisense)

Note: although a "microsoft made" php intellisense is being discussed, they will allow user made intellisense implementations.

> Our extensibility story will support creating IntelliSense and Debugging for additional languages/runtimes.
>
> Sean McBreen
> Visual Studio Code – Team Member

Comment: Can you please add the related text from the links that answers the question? This is to avoid losing content because of expired links.

Comment: Note, i don't have enough rep to post a third link so i had to remove this one: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vscode 
It's the link to the blog mentionned in the first quote.